# objective-c macro for a variadic function

Tags: objective-c, macros, variadic-functions

Here's an example of what i'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to create a macro, that would look like this:

```
SOMEMACRO(obj, obj, obj, ..., obj);
```

The macro would compile to:

```
some_function(obj, obj, obj, ..., obj, SOMETHING_ELSE, SOMETHING_ELSE);
```

Here's an example macro for a 1 parameter function:

```
#define SOMEMACRO(x) some_function(x, SOMETHING_ELSE, SOMETHING_ELSE)
```

But it only works with one parameter (x)

So basically i need the same thing but so that i could pass a viariable number of arguments. It would be nice that the compiler took whatever is between ( and ) and simply replaced X with it. I'm not sure if i was very clear about the problem, but i hope you understood.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define SOMEMACRO(...) some_func(__VA_ARGS__, SOMETHING_ELSE, SOMETHING_ELSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i gave up on searching too early i guess. To answer my own question:

The macro for a variadic function looks like this:

```
#define MACRONAME(...) some_function(__VA_ARGS__, SOMETHING_ELSE, SOMETHING_ELSE)
```